# MAKEFILE get list of files and join

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, makefile

I am trying to collect a list of files of a certain type and join them to one file, then place them in an area of my application, this is how it looks

```
FILETYPE_DIRECTORY = /mydirectory
FILETYPE_SRCFILES = $(find $(FILETYPE_DIRECTORY)/ -type f -and -name '*.ft')

filetype-collected: $(FILETYPE_SRCFILES)
     mkdir $(FILETYPE_DIRECTORY)/filetype-collected;
     cat $(FILETYPE_SRCFILES) > compressed.ft;
     mv compressed.ft $(FILETYPE_DIRECTORY)/filetype-collected;
```

The response I get is this

```
mkdir /mydirectory/filetype-collected;
cat  > compressed.ft;
```

And the application does not continue (no filetype has been joined), what is the problem - O also tried substituting

```
cat $(FILETYPE_SRCFILES)
```

with

```
cat $(wildcard $(FILETYPE_SRCFILES))
```

Sorry if this is really basic, I am new to MAKEFILEs

Comment: What do you get when you add `echo $(FILETYPE_SRCFILES)` to the actions?

Comment: You do have TABs before each action do you?  (There's not here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably won't work.  Try:

```
FILETYPE_SRCFILES = $(shell find $(FILETYPE_DIRECTORY)/ -type f -and -name '*.ft')
```

instead of what you've got for `FILETYPE_SRCFILES`.  You could also write this which seems a little clearer to me with one less step:

```
$(FILETYPE_DIRECTORY)/filetype-collected/compressed.ft : $(FILETYPE_SRCFILES)
        mkdir $(dir $@)
        cat $^ > $@
```

Comment: For the OP: you should use `:=`, not `=`, when assigning from a `$(shell ...)` function.  The former is MUCH more efficient (using the latter every time you use the variable the entire shell command will be run again from scratch).  And I'd use `mkdir -p`, not `mkdir`, for safety.